# Can we use Swift toolchain to checkout/compile a Xcode project?

Tags: swift, xcode, ubuntu

I got to checkout the source code of an IOS application, It is an Xcode project and I do not own a Mac.
I created a virtual machine on Ubuntu to use the Swift toolchain as the app is coded in Swift.
Is it necessary to keep the XCode file in the project to compile it or not ?
And if not, how can I compile it ?

Comment: Just guessing, but you'll need to learn how to build at the command line - which you can. Xcode will not run anywhere but on a Mac. But, like virtually all languages nowadays, you can port the source code. That means (probably) a lot of manually labor... exporting source code as is, (again) learning the command lines needed to make a build... and two *very* important things to consider: (1) Is there a Swift language build available for your version of Ubuntu along with further-proofing, and (2) will you be able to *deliver* your product to your customer? (Think App Store submission.)

Comment: You cannot compile an iOS app on Linux, with or without Xcode files. Sure, Swift *the programming language* is open source, but the iOS SDKs are not. On Linux with Swift you can only do server stuff, scripting, CLI apps, etc, not iOS or macOS apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst Swift is available on other platforms (e.g. Linux), the iOS SDK are not and will require macOS to compile. The simplest & cheapest option is to get an old Mac mini.